# Multithreaded game program suddenly locks up on glXSwapBuffers

Tags: linux, multithreading, alsa, glx

I'm polishing up a Linux game program I wrote, and after about 10 minutes of playing, it suddenly slows down to 1 frame per thirty seconds or so, slowing the entire system down as well. Even after interrupting the process, the system continues to be slow for about a minute.

In multiple tests I've interrupted the process in GDB when the slowdown occurs, and it is always in the middle of a call to `glXSwapBuffers`.

It happens regardless of game state or input. The only thing that prevents it is not beginning playback of a repeating music track in a separate thread: the thread still runs, but it doesn't constantly write to the sound card buffer. I've ensured that two shared lists are properly locked.

Has anybody run into a problem with `glXSwapBuffers` and other, seemingly unrelated threads?

The OS is Ubuntu 9, using the Mesa 7.6.0 implementation of OpenGL and ALSA libasound2 1.0.20-3. I updated my NVIDIA drivers for my GeForce 6800 graphics card this morning, but to no avail.

(Relevant?) code follows.

Display functions:

```
int DisplayInterface::init()
{   
    xDisplay = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (xDisplay == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: cannot connect to the X server\n");
        return -1;
    }

    rootWindow = DefaultRootWindow(xDisplay);

    fbConfigs = glXChooseFBConfig(xDisplay, DefaultScreen(xDisplay), fbAttributes, &numConfigs);
    if (fbConfigs == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: no X framebuffer configuration available as specified\n");
        return -1;
    }

    visualInfo = glXGetVisualFromFBConfig(xDisplay, fbConfigs[0]);
    if (visualInfo == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: no appropriate X visual found\n");
        return -1;
    }

    colorMap = XCreateColormap(xDisplay, rootWindow, visualInfo->visual, AllocNone);
    xAttributes.colormap = colorMap;
    xAttributes.event_mask = ExposureMask | KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask; // need KeyPress and KeyRelease for InputInterface

    gameWindow = XCreateWindow(xDisplay, rootWindow, 0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight, 0, visualInfo->depth, InputOutput, visualInfo->visual, CWColormap | CWEventMask, &xAttributes);
    XMapWindow(xDisplay, gameWindow);
    XStoreName(xDisplay, gameWindow, "Vuess Vow Vong Vo Vold Vown Vhe Vey");

    glxWindow = glXCreateWindow(xDisplay, fbConfigs[0], gameWindow, NULL);

    renderContext = glXCreateNewContext(xDisplay, fbConfigs[0], GLX_RGBA_TYPE, NULL, GL_TRUE);
    glXMakeContextCurrent(xDisplay, glxWindow, glxWindow, renderContext);

    //glViewport(0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight);
    glViewport(-2.0 * displayWidth, -2.0 * displayHeight, 5.0 * displayWidth, 5.0 * displayHeight);

    //glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    //glLoadIdentity();
    //gluOrtho2D(0.0, (GLfloat)displayWidth, 0.0, (GLfloat)displayHeight);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glPixelZoom((GLfloat)((float)displayWidth / (float) pictureWidth), (GLfloat)((float)displayHeight / (float) pictureHeight));

    glClearColor((float)clearColor[0] / 255.0, (float)clearColor[1] / 255.0, (float)clearColor[2] / 255.0, (float)clearColor[3] / 255.0);

    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    return 0;
}

// draw a Sprite from left to right and from top to bottom, starting at the given pixel
void DisplayInterface::draw(Sprite *sprite, Pixel& pixel)
{
    if (sprite == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    pixelstorage_t *spritePixels = sprite->getPixelData();
    const unsigned int format = sprite->getPixelFormat();

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-2.0 * (GLfloat)displayWidth, 3.0 * (GLfloat)displayWidth, -2.0 * (GLfloat)displayHeight, 3.0 * (GLfloat)displayHeight);
    glRasterPos2i(pixel.x * (int)displayWidth / (int)pictureWidth, (int)displayHeight - (pixel.y + (int)sprite->getHeight()) * (int)displayHeight / (int)pictureHeight);
    switch (format)
    {
        case SPRITE_RGBA:
            glDrawPixels(sprite->getWidth(), sprite->getHeight(), GL_RGBA, PIXEL_TYPE, spritePixels);
    }
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void DisplayInterface::finalizeFrame()
{   
    glFinish();
    glXSwapBuffers(xDisplay, glxWindow);
}
```

Playback thread functions:

```
int writeFramesToHwBuffer(pcmsamplestorage_t *frames, snd_pcm_sframes_t numframes)
{
    int pcmreturn;

    while ((pcmreturn = snd_pcm_writei(pcm_handle, frames, numframes)) < 0)
    {
        snd_pcm_prepare(pcm_handle);
        fprintf(stderr, "Speaker Interface error: hardware buffer underrun.\n");
    }
    return pcmreturn;
}

void *playback(void *arg)
{
    int i;

    unsigned int availableframes;
    unsigned int framesFromThisBuffer;
    unsigned int framesThisTime;

    pcmsamplestorage_t *frames_mix;
    pcmsamplestorage_t *frames_track;
    unsigned int framesOffset;

    std::list<struct playbackState *>::iterator stateIter;

    while (1)
    {
        if (snd_pcm_wait(pcm_handle, 1000) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Speaker Interface error: poll failed.\n");
            break;
        }

        if ((availableframes = snd_pcm_avail_update(pcm_handle)) < 0)
        {
            if (availableframes == -EPIPE)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Speaker Interface error: an xrun occured.\n");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Speaker Interface error: unknown ALSA avail update return value (%d).\n", availableframes);
                break;
            }
        }

        // mix and write more frequently than necessary
        while (availableframes > 0)
        {
            framesThisTime = std::min(availableframes, 1024u);
            availableframes -= framesThisTime;
            //printf("Frames this time: %d / frames left to go: %d\n", framesThisTime, availableframes);

            frames_mix = new pcmsamplestorage_t[framesThisTime * 2];
            for (i = 0; i < framesThisTime * 2; i++)
            {
                frames_mix[i] = 0;
            }

            // BEGIN CRITICAL SECTION
            if (pthread_mutex_lock(&soundslists_lock) != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Speaker Interface error: couldn't lock sounds lists from playback thread.\n");
            }

            printf("soundsPlaying has %d elements.\n", (int)soundsPlaying.size());
            printf("soundsToStop has %d elements.\n", (int)soundsToStop.size());

            for (stateIter = soundsPlaying.begin(); stateIter != soundsPlaying.end(); stateIter++)
            {
                frames_track = (*stateIter)->sound->getSamples();

                if ((*stateIter)->deliveredframes < (*stateIter)->totalframes)
                {
                    if ((*stateIter)->repeating)
                    {
                        framesFromThisBuffer = framesThisTime;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // mix in silence if we reach the end of this sound's buffer
                        framesFromThisBuffer = std::min(framesThisTime, (*stateIter)->totalframes - (*stateIter)->deliveredframes);                 
                    }

                    for (i = 0; i < framesFromThisBuffer * 2; i++)
                    {
                        // add samples to the mix, potentially running off the end of this buffer and wrapping around
                        if (SHRT_MAX - frames_mix[i] < frames_track[((*stateIter)->deliveredframes * 2 + i) % ((*stateIter)->totalframes * 2)])
                        {
                            // prevent overflow
                            frames_mix[i] = SHRT_MAX;
                        }
                        else if (SHRT_MIN - frames_mix[i] > frames_track[((*stateIter)->deliveredframes * 2 + i) % ((*stateIter)->totalframes * 2)])
                        {
                            // prevent underflow
                            frames_mix[i] = SHRT_MIN;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            frames_mix[i] += frames_track[((*stateIter)->deliveredframes * 2 + i) % ((*stateIter)->totalframes * 2)];
                        }
                    }

                    (*stateIter)->deliveredframes = ((*stateIter)->deliveredframes + framesFromThisBuffer);
                    if ((*stateIter)->repeating)
                    {
                        (*stateIter)->deliveredframes = (*stateIter)->deliveredframes % (*stateIter)->totalframes;
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    soundsToStop.push_back(stateIter);
                }
            }

            writeFramesToHwBuffer(frames_mix, framesThisTime);

            delete frames_mix;

            for (std::list<std::list<struct playbackState *>::iterator>::iterator stateiterIter = soundsToStop.begin(); stateiterIter != soundsToStop.end(); stateiterIter++)
            {
                soundsPlaying.erase(*stateiterIter);
                free(**stateiterIter);
                stateiterIter = soundsToStop.erase(stateiterIter);
            }

            if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&soundslists_lock) != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Speaker Interface error: couldn't unlock sounds lists from playback thread.\n");
            }
            // END CRITICAL SECTION
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use gdb from another host? (e.g. via ssh) If not, gdb itself may be blocked by whatever is causing the lockup. My guess would be that this is either a driver problem, or you are somehow leaking some kind of object, which becomes exhausted.

Comment: I ran it through Valgrind memcheck, and fixed a few things until it reported no memory loss, but the problem persists on my machine. However, I've tested it on a couple of other machines, and I can't reproduce the problem. So, it's probably a driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

> The OS is Ubuntu 9, using the **Mesa** 7.6.0 implementation of OpenGL and ALSA libasound2 1.0.20-3. I updated my **NVIDIA** drivers for my GeForce 6800 graphics card this morning, but to no avail.

You can be using a Mesa libGL.so, or NVIDIA libGL.so, but not both at the same time.  I suggest you try a different OpenGL driver (e.g. really use Mesa. Check `glxinfo | grep OpenGL.vendor`)

As a wild guess: `glXSwapBuffers` often will interface with the vertical sync on your screen, you might try playing with options for that (see Google).